# What are APG and AEO7 and should I be concerned?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, safety

I'm considering importing some granite cleaner for my stone business to save some money and the following is the list of ingredients:

APG, AEO7, silicone oil, water, White Mineral Oil

My question is should I be concerned about any of these ingredients?
 May primary concern is "AGP" and "AE07" as I do not know what these are.

Comment: The company supplying the product are required (in the USA/UK) to provide a material safety data sheet (msds) which explains what chemicals are in the product and any known hazards. This should be available on their website or through rmailing them. The msds is often a little vague but should tell you about any associated hazards/risks and the appropriate cautions to take.

Comment: I'd also echo the MSDS - some searching doesn't turn up what "APG" or "AGP" or "AE07" are. They are probably some sort of abbreviation, but the company is obligated to provide safety information in the US and UK (and likely EU as well).

Comment: [APG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkyl_polyglycoside) = alkyl polyglycoside and [AEO7](http://www.made-in-china.com/showroom/transfarxdh/product-detailbMYQiUeOCqto/China-Laurel-Fatty-Alcohol-Ethoxylate-AEO3-AEO7-AEO9-.html) =  aliphatic alcohol and ethylene oxide adduct. Both are non-ionic surfactants.